# How to group two lists of class objects based on an Attribute efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, performance, loops, class, for-loop

I have two lists that both contain Objects from the same class. I want to group them together in a third list that contains lists or tuples of Objects with the same attribute value.

Example

```
Object1.time = 1 
Object2.time = 2
Object3.time = 1
Object4.time = 2
Objekt5.time = 3


list1 = [Object1, Object2]
list2 = [Object3,Object4]
```

There result of the sorting should look like this:

`result_list = [[Object1,Object3], [Object2,Object4], [Object5]]`

I need to mention: I don't need the lists that contain only one object!

so, the final list should look like this:

`final_result = [[Objekt1, Objekt3], [Objekt2, Objekt4]]`

List1 contains 1500 objects, List2 over 70,000 the Problem is: if I use two for-loops to compare the objects it takes too long.

Here is my inefficient example:

````
class Example:
    def __init__(self,time,example_attribute):
        self.time = time
        self.example_attribute = example_attribute

test_list1 = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,9]
test_list2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","d","e","f","g","h","i"]

test_list3 = ["j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u"]


object_list1 = []
for i,j in zip(test_list1,test_list2):
    object_list1.append(Example(i,j))

object_list2 = []
for i,j in zip(test_list1,test_list3):
    object_list2.append(Example(i,j))


# How to group both lists together by the time attribute? This part takes too long.
group_by_time = []
for i in object_list1:
    my_list = [i]
    for j in object_list2:
        if i.time == j.time:
            my_list.append(j)
    group_by_time.append(my_list)

for sub_list in group_by_time:
    for index, item in enumerate(sub_list):
        if index == 0:
            print(item.time, ",",item.example_attribute,end =",")
        else:print(item.example_attribute, end = ",")
    print("")```
````

Answer (score 4):

Use a dictionary, which is how you idiomatically group things:

```
import itertools

grouped = {}
for obj in itertools.chain(list1, list2):
    grouped.setdefault(obj.time, []).append(obj)
```

Now you have a dictionary mapping the time attribute to a list of objects. You can get a list of list if you really want, something like:

```
final = list(grouped.values())
```

If you want to omit lists with only a single value, you can do something like:

```
final = [v for v in grouped.values() if len(v) > 1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was completely fixated on lists, I did not think about dictionaries!

Comment: I have a question, instead of ```itertools.chain()``` could I just use ```list1 + list2```?. Does itertools have any advantages here?

Comment: @RaphaelPrinz yes, you could, but using `chain` doesn't create another list.